# Dot product of a vector with each vector in another matrix

Tags: python, numpy

```py
weight = np.array([[[ 0.38932115, -0.27430567]],

       [[-0.04543304, -0.05643598]],

       [[ 0.46912688, -0.07695298]]])

data = np.array([[-0.2056065,  0.7889058]])

like,

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

I want to take the dot product of the row in data with each row in weight, how could I accomplish this? I tried tensordot but it seems a bit convoluted / non-obvious the way axes works. Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `row` and `vector` is a bit ambiguous:

```
In [7]: weight = np.array([[[ 0.38932115, -0.27430567]],
   ...: 
   ...:        [[-0.04543304, -0.05643598]],
   ...: 
   ...:        [[ 0.46912688, -0.07695298]]])
   ...: 
   ...: data = np.array([[-0.2056065,  0.7889058]])
In [8]: weight.shape
Out[8]: (3, 1, 2)
In [9]: data.shape
Out[9]: (1, 2)
```

Are your rows of shape (2,) or (1,2)?

`dot` is a 'sum of products' function, but sum on which axis?

With `einsum` we can control the sum axis.

Sum on both the 1 and 2's:

```
In [11]: np.einsum('ijk,jk',weight, data)
Out[11]: array([-0.29644829, -0.03518134, -0.15716419])   # shape (3,)
```

or just the 1's:

```
In [12]: np.einsum('ijk,jm',weight, data)
Out[12]: 
array([[[-0.08004696,  0.30713771],
        [ 0.05639903, -0.21640133]],

       [[ 0.00934133, -0.03584239],
        [ 0.0116036 , -0.04452267]],

       [[-0.09645554,  0.37009692],
        [ 0.01582203, -0.06070865]]])
In [13]: _.shape
Out[13]: (3, 2, 2)
```

Or just the 2's:

```
In [14]: np.einsum('ijk,mk',weight, data)
Out[14]: 
array([[[-0.29644829]],

       [[-0.03518134]],

       [[-0.15716419]]])

In [16]: _.shape
Out[16]: (3, 1, 1)
```

`matmul/@` also does this sum - `data.T` changes the (1,2) array to a (2,1).  This pairs the (3,1,2) with a (2,1) to fit the "Last A with the second to the last of B" rule for `dot/@`.

```
In [17]: weight @ data.T
Out[17]: 
array([[[-0.29644829]],

       [[-0.03518134]],

       [[-0.15716419]]])
```

You ask about a multidimensional `data`.  Just what do you mean by that?  It already is 2d.  Do you mean a (n,2) array, or a (n,1,2)?  What's the relation between this `n` dimension and the 3 dimension of `weight`?  No hand waving please :)

Answer (score 1):

First transpose `data` before taking the [dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) product.

```
>>> weight.dot(data.T)
array([[[-0.29644829]],
       [[-0.03518134]],
       [[-0.15716419]]])

# Multiple rows of data.
data = np.array([[-0.2056065,  0.7889058],
                 [0.7889058, -.2056065]])

>>> weight.dot(data.T)
array([[[-0.29644829,  0.36353674]],
       [[-0.03518134, -0.02423878]],
       [[-0.15716419,  0.38591895]]])
```

Comment: Well, that _is_ the definition of the dot product. Two vectors of equal length.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product  It will work, however, if `data` has multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `np.apply_along_axis`

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:np.dot(x,data.T),2,weight)
```

which gives

```
array([[[-0.29644829]],

       [[-0.03518134]],

       [[-0.15716419]]])
```

If `data` contains more than one row, this will also work, for example

```
weight = np.array([[[ 0.38932115, -0.27430567]],

       [[-0.04543304, -0.05643598]],

       [[ 0.46912688, -0.07695298]]])

data = np.array([[-0.2056065,  0.7889058],[-0.2056065,  0.7889058]]) 
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:np.dot(x,data.T),2,weight)
```

gives you

```
array([[[-0.29644829, -0.29644829]],

       [[-0.03518134, -0.03518134]],

       [[-0.15716419, -0.15716419]]])
```

Comment: @PyWalker2797 yes, it does.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is slower than the multidimensional `dot/matmul`.  It iterates on the first dimension of `weight`.